# apache 2.4 exclude img from access log

Tags: apache

How do i exclude img files from my apache access log?
I can't get it to work. I have tried to add this

```
  ## flag robots.txt requests
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" robots-request=log
  ## flag favicon requests
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/favicon\.ico$" favicon-request=nolog

  ## flag image requests
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg)$" image-request=nolog

  ## flag Css and JS requests
  SetEnvIf Request_URI \.css css-request=nolog
  SetEnvIf Request_URI \.js js-request=nolog

   ## flag cron calls
   SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^/cron\.php|^/bgp-start/)" cron-request=nolog

   ## set do_not_log if any of the above flags are set
   SetEnvIf robots-request nolog do_not_log
   SetEnvIf favicon-request nolog do_not_log
   SetEnvIf image-request nolog do_not_log
   SetEnvIf css-request nolog do_not_log
   SetEnvIf js-request nolog do_not_log
   SetEnvIf cron-request nolog do_not_log
```

I added this to my apache2.conf

Comment: grep -r for your CustomLog directives and make sure they have !do_not_log at th eend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add directives SetEnvIf and CustomLog to vhost configuration, such as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn

  SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.png$|\.gif$|\.jpg$|\.js$|\.css$" is_exclude
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!is_exclude
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Oleg don't work for me ( 5 years after he posted ), but was close.

I have to  remove backslashes, in order to work.
Taken from https://ma.ttias.be/apache-access-log-dont-log-static-content/

Specs:

Server version: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
                                                                          Server built:   2022-06-09T04:26:43

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|ico) static=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127.0.0.1" dontlog=yes
CustomLog ${docroot}/access_log combined expr=!(reqenv('static')=='yes'||reqenv('dontlog')=='yes')
```